# Tab bar missing from view controller when shortcutting from app delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, appdelegate

I am trying to shortcut straight to a particular view within my app from the app delegate. So far I have got to the point where the view presents with the navigation bar, however the dismiss view controller button which I have in the navigation bar doesn't do anything, and the tab bar is missing.

This is the code I have:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let mainRootController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("favourites") as UIViewController
    if self.window != nil {
        let navigationController: UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController
        navigationController.viewControllers = [mainRootController]

        self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
    }
```

I have an initial view controller with a hidden navigation bar which I had to add to get the above code to work (I don't want that view to have a navigation bar). I am trying to skip that initial view controller and jump to the main part of my app which has a tab bar. The favourites view is the third tab.

This is the layout of my storyboard (before I added the navigation bar at the entry point). I've pointed to the view controller I'm trying to get to:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Hide bottom Bar on Push" option in your view controller. It's can be set in storyboard or programmatically as well

[image]

Comment: It's definitely set to false unfortunately.